# CreateItem(0) Failing when in Scheduled Task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have PowerShell script to send email. This works perfectly well when I run it directly.

It's failing when I schedule it via Task Scheduler. Below is the code

```
# Get Outlook Object
if (Get-Process Outlook) {
    $outlook = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
} else {
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
}

$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "x@y.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Test Test TEst"
$Mail.Body = "Test Test TEst"
$Mail.Send()
```

`$Outlook.CreateItem(0)` is the one which is failing.
The error:

```
The term 'Outlook.CreateItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Temp\SendMail.PS1:9 char:31
+ $Mail = Outlook.CreateItem <<<< (0)
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Outlook.CreateItem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"
```

Comment: I have copied the error to the OP.  My guess is that you don't run it under the correct user.  Please information about the task scheduler job (especially under which user you are running it).

Comment: What @tukan said + whether you run it with highest privileges (in scheduled task settings). For me that works perfectly but only if I run in the same context (without administrative permissions)

Comment: @robdy, I tested that. It doesn't help. Thanks for the response though

Comment: Are you running the task as "system" or allowing it run when you aren't logged in? If I remember rightly Outlook needs to have a "proper" login to function so if you are trying to run as system or without you being logged in it will error. Try logging in to the machine, setting the task to run as your user account with "Run only when user logged on" set and see how you get on.

Comment: Your error message (once formatted properly) clearly says that your *actual* code attempts to invoke `Outlook.CreateItem`, not `$Outlook.CreateItem` as your sample code claims. Please do not post things you fabricated or typed from memory. Create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem, and post *that* code and the error you receive from *that* code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Its good observation. I will try to post screenshot of error.

Comment: Just copy/paste the error *as text* from your PowerShell console.